# curve fitting with scipy curvefit in python

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to do some curve fitting. I have a measured curve which I believe would be my `Y` data, and I'm attempting to fit it with a weighted sum of a number of other curves which I believe would be my `X` data.

My latest attempt to try to accomplish this is below but I have several errors and I decided to ask if someone can help point out what I am doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

ydata = np.array([1.0, 7.0, 4.0])
xdata = np.array([[0.0, 1.0],[3.5, 0.0],[1.0, 2.0]])

def fitfunc(xdata, *params):
    ctx = 0.0
    for n in np.nditer(c):
        ctx = c[n]*xdata[:,n] + ctx
    return ctx

# initial guesses for fitting parameters, answer for this simple example is 2.0, 1.0
c = np.array([0.6, 0.3])

# fit data using SciPy's Levenberg-Marquart method
nlfit, nlpcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitfunc, xdata, ydata, p0=[c], sigma=None)

print(nlfit)
```

Apologies as there will undoubtedly be errors everywhere in this, but hopefully my description of what I am trying to accomplish is clear

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are dealing with a curve fitting problem? It appears that your are trying to approximate the vector `ydata` as a linear combination of two vectors `xdata[:,0]`, `xdata[:,1]`, which is essentially a linear algebra problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `fitfunc` loops over the parameters of `c`, but `n` is actually the values of `c`, not the indices. It is trying to run e.g. `ctx = c[0.6]*xdata[:,0.6] + ctx`.
2. `fitfunc` uses the fixed, global `c`, and not the parameters passed to it by `curve_fit`. It should refer to `params`, not `c`.

What you want instead is

```
def fitfunc(xdata, *params):
    ctx = 0.0
    for n in range(len(params)):
        ctx = params[n]*xdata[:,n] + ctx
    return ctx
```

We can see that it works by running it by itself with `print(fitfunc(xdata, *c))`, which returns `[ 0.3  2.1  1.2]`.

Note that the `*c` in `print(fitfunc(xdata, *c))` takes the elements of `c` and passes them as separate arguments, instead of as a single array. This is equivalent to writing `fitfunc(xdata, c[0], c[1])`.

As Stelios noted in the comments, this is matrix multiplication, `xdata[:,0] * c[0] + xdata[:,1] * c[1]`. You can use `np.matmul`, which is likely faster, as in:

```
def fitfunc(xdata, *params):
    return np.matmul(xdata, params)
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  I did wonder if this part of my problem was linear.  Prior to now I have used the Solver in Excel, but someone convinced me I should learn Python and it certainly looks incredibly powerful.  My example is simple and possibly some additional manipulations which I would like to make, such as allowing the columns to move up or down by steps to obtain the best fit, due to noise and experimental displacements in real data, may make it non linear?  But I will proceed one step at a time and see if I can get this part working first.  Thank you again, steve.

Comment: This particular approach will always be linear, since the function you are fitting is linear -- y = b1*x1 + b2*x2. The [curve_fit documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) has an example of a non-linear function -- y = a*e^(b*x) + c. I recommend looking at scatterplots of your data to see if there is any obvious non-linearity.

Comment: Thank you again, the code now does exactly what I want it to.    I have opted for the simpler fitfunc using matrix multiplication. Some of what was suggested indicates that I should look at solutions using linear algebra so I will read up on how I might solve this type of problem with that approach rather than the curvefit one, as this will all be new to me.  I will also look into possible ways that I might be able to allow the columns of my xdata to 'slide' up and down relative to one another for cases where that feature would improve the fit.